# Regex - check for a special token not followed by any character until the end of string

Tags: regex

So what I want to do is following: I have a special character `@`, which I want to  capture, if and only if it is not followed by any alphabetic character up until the very end of the document. So:

- `@\n\n  ASBCDSA` - should fail
- `@\n\n\n\n\t` - should pass

Any idea how it should be done?

Comment: Which language/regex engine? Are `\n` literal characters or representative of newline characters?

Comment: `@[^a-zA-Z]+\z`

Comment: `@[^a-z]*\z` with case-insensitive matching (same as Toto's, just matching zero-length and using modifier). You can also use `@[^a-z]*+$`

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your example, you want `@` to be the last character, followed only by whitespace. In that case, you want `@\s*\z`, which will only match if there's nothing but tabs, spaces, or newlines after the `@` to the end of the document.

(If that's not the case, and you're fine with symbols, numbers, and other things, you can do `@[^\w]*\z` instead.)

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/IVDmuq/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to capture the `@` character, then use lookahead:

```
(?i)@(?=[^a-z]*\z)
```

1. `(?i)` Set the case insensitive flag.
2. `@` Look for a `@`.
3. `(?=[^a-z]*\z)` If and only if the `@` if followed by 0 or more non-alphabetic characters followed by the end of string.